# Console.log font size in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, console.log

Can the font size be controlled from inside a NodeJS app when logging with `console.log()`?

I'm only interested in changing it at runtime and not changing it in the terminal settings.

Comment: Pardon? Terminal uses fixed font. There are some ways for some terminals to change font for entire terminal, but I doubt that it's what you want.

Comment: @AlexeyTen What if the fond is changed twice? Will the sizes be maintained or all the text will be reset at the same size?

Comment: Changing the terminal font-size is out of scope of a node.js app. You can only control the color and style (underline etc) with this https://www.npmjs.org/package/colors.

Comment: @laggingreflex That's what I wanted to know. Please add an answer with an explanation. And keep in mind I'm not interested in colors anything else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way [console.log](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console) works is that the output is sent to **stdout** or **stderr**, which are [the standard stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) provided by the OS to the application (nodejs) where it writes its output data. 
You can only pass text and [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)s to control the formatting of the text.

There's no option to control the font-size of the terminal text from within your node.js app.